# What does FTM mean on my phone?

Tags: factory-reset

I have a Telstra smart-touch Next Gen. I wanted to get rid of my google account so I went to settings-privacy-factory reset. Everything was perfectly fine until I tuned off my phone and when I tried to turn it back on. The only thing it says now is 'FTM'. I can't do anything to the screen not even turn it off again.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

FTM = Field Test Mode

Try removing the battery to turn the device off. Replace the battery and then turn the phone back on and you should be out of FTM.

FTM, i believe, is usually entered by holding a button combination down when turning the phone on. Sounds like you accidentally figured out that combo when you turned it on. It could be as simple as "holding the power button while turning on".