# what if you cant get out of FTM but you tried taking the battery out and putting it back in?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

what do you do when your phone is on FTM mode and wont get out even  though you tried taking the battery out and putting it back in?

Comment: This would have been the dupe question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15581/what-does-ftm-mean-on-my-phone

Comment: Have you tried taking out the battery for a longer period of time - like 5 minutes?